# How to implement "product gallery" feature of woocommerce into a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, photo-gallery, woocommerce-theming

I'm wondering if there is a way to borrow the "product gallery" feature of woocommerce and add it to a custom post type in wordpress.

[image]

I know i can go through the woocommerce source codes and search and find its nuts and bolts and pieces in the woocommerce plugin folder, put them together and customize them for a specific custom post type. I know these are some of the corresponding files in the woocommerce plugin folder:

- For its javascript:

  - meta-boxes-product.js
  - single-product.js
- For rendering its html template:

  - wc-template-functions.php > There is `wc_get_gallery_image_html` function
  - class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php

    - `add_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images', __( 'Product gallery', 'woocommerce' ), 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Images::output', 'product', 'side', 'low' );`
  - class-wc-meta-box-product-images.php
  - etc.

**BUT** this is prone to errors and bugs. I'm wondering if there is a `better`, `easier`, `more elegant`, `less buggy` way to implement this feature to a custom post type. Maybe there is a `hook` and/or a `class` somewhere that you guys know about and i'm missing here.

Just to clarify my question, i actually have a custom post type it's called "projects". I need a **gallery** for this custom post type which accepts new images for my custom post type, so i thought i could use the "product gallery" feature from woocommerce instead of writing a gallery from scratch for my custom post type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but if you could get the
product_id
inside your CPT file try this code:

```
<?php
$product_id = '14';
$product = new WC_product($product_id);
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
    {
      // Display the image URL
      echo $Original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

      // Display Image instead of URL
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');

    }
?>
```

This should work!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify my question, i actually have a custom post type it's called "projects". I need a gallery for this custom post type which accepts new images for my custom post type, so i thought i could use the "product gallery" feature from woocommerce instead of writing a gallery from scratch for my custom post type. So, i'm not trying to loop through images of a specific product.

Comment: Ok know I see.. Thus, you could do it in many ways.. You could try a page builder like Elementor or WP Bekary or even a plugin like ACF. Do you have any of these? Otherwise, you could use a plugin gallery (there are lots of them for a simple gallery) and use a shortcode that plugin will give you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes those are valid ways to build a gallery feature, but, like i said, i don't want to reinvent the wheel and create a gallery from scratch. I would like to use the gallery feature that already exists and offered by woocommerce.

Comment: You are not reinvent the wheel and create anything from scratch.. If you want to use a gallery from a WC product you could use the code I suggest above. In order to do that, you should send the product_id dynamically, according to which Product gallery you want to display in your template. If you want to use a plugin and/or a builder Page, you could just pick the images you want and and a shortcode (by copy - paste) inside your Custom Template "projects". You need to write some code to display the gallery, it can not be otherwise..